# Play MIDI file with Python matplotlib animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, midi

I used `animation.FuncAnimation` from `[matplotlib]`[here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html) to create a `mp4` video and saved it as an `mp4` file.

Is there a way to play a MIDI file as audio along with the video in Python?

Comment: This seems to be an unsupported feature https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7212

Comment: Pygame (currently) does not support MP4 video files, only mpeg2.

Comment: @Kingsley is there any workaround you could suggest?

Comment: Well if the goal is to simply add the audio to the mp4 file and replay it as per any other MP4 video - use something like the `midi2audio` module (or some other tool) to convert the midi audio to a `.wav` file - https://pypi.org/project/midi2audio/  Then use **FFMpeg** to remultiplex the audio into the video file.  `ffmpeg -i myvideo.mp4 -i myaudio.wav -c copy new_file.mp4`

Comment: The objective was to synchronize the MIDI file with an animation in the mp4 video created using `matplotlib`.